# Count button clicks with timer in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, timer

I'm trying to simulate sms application with keyboard input like in older phones where you had to click f.e. button "2" two times to type letter "b", three times for "c" etc. I have several buttons, and for each I need to set some kind of delay so I can click as many times as I want to get needed letter or symbol. I know there is java.util.Timer that can be handy here, but I don't understand how to apply it in this situation and how to turn delay only after first click on "button" not after every next.
Below is a sample FXML element I'm using in my code and a method that gets called when a button is clicked.

```
...
@FXML
Button button_2;

...

public void handleButton2(){
    //Code to execute to count clicks ?
    ...
    //Array of Strings instead of Characters to use .appendText without parsing
    String []letters = {"a", "b", "c", "2"};
    sms_text_area.appendText(letters[/*index of letter*/]);
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only want to change the string represented by the button if it was the last one clicked.

In general, to perform something after a delay, use a `PauseTransition`.

So just introduce some extra fields:

```
private Button lastButtonClicked ;
private int buttonClickCount ;

private final PauseTransition buttonPressDelay 
    = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5));
```

and then

```
public void handleButton2(){

    String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c", "2"};

    buttonPressDelay.setOnFinished(e -> {
        sms_text_area.appendText(letters[buttonClickCount]);
        lastButtonClicked = null ;
    });

    if (lastButtonClicked == button_2) {
        buttonClickCount = (buttonClickCount + 1) % letters.length ;
    } else {
        buttonClickCount = 0 ;
    }
    buttonPressDelay.playFromStart();
    lastButtonClicked = button_2 ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this way I still need additional controller to actually get number of counts, what I was asking is a way to set delay for call to handle method. So code first counts number of clicks and then automatically calls for handler without any additional user interaction. I.E. clicked two times button "2", after ~half second controller gets the number of clicks and appends letter with index of number of clicks.

Comment: Sorry, clicked "enter" to early, updated the comment.

Comment: I'm having trouble remembering how texting on those phones worked :). See update, but I don't think that's quite right....

Comment: Well that seems to work, do I nest this method inside handleButton2 method, or call it from there to actually append letter to text area?

Comment: If I just add sms_text_area.appendText(letters[buttonClickCount]); in the end of this method I will append the letter after delay, but it also appends letters every time I do a single click. So when I click 2 times and wait I don't get "b" in textarea, I see "abb".

Comment: @StanRedoute It doesn't add the letter after the delay with the method the way I wrote it?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I forgot to disconnect the old controller, your code works fine, I only added lastButtonClicked = null; inside buttonPressDelay.setOnFinished lambda to reset count if the same button clicked again right after.

Comment: @StanRedoute Ah yes, good point. I made that change in the answer.